# Horizontal Navigation Bar CSS - center logo and text

Tags: css, html, alignment, navigationbar

I have a navigation bar with a logo inside and I was able to do it, but I was not able to align properly the text and the figure.

I would like to align the text in the center, considering the height of the logo.

Please any ideas? I tried to change many things, but did not work. In my code here, I only put a other logo as an example, my original logo is very big.

Also I do not want a background color in my logo, only in the text.

```
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <title>data</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="noble"><img src="http://news.olemiss.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/MoW-Logo.jpg" width="140"></a></li>

      <li><a class="active" href="index.htm">Home</a></li>

      <li><a href="#classes">Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="#DE">Photos</a></li>

       <li style="float:right"><a href="#help">Help</a></li>

      <li class="dropdown" style="float:right">
        <a href="#about" class="dropbtn">About</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="team.htm">Team</a>
          <a href="events.htm">Events</a>
              </div> </li>
              </ul>

    <h1> Text....</h1>

    </body>
    </html>
```

My CSS code is:

```
#nav a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: #FFF;
  }

ul {list-style-type: none;
    font-family:calibri;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
    height: 90px;
  }

body {font-family:Times New Roman;line-height: 1.5em;}


li {float: left;}

li a {display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;}

a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #5E9F49;}

.active {background-color:#9DC690;}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #5E9F49;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color:#9DC690;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: are you doing this without any framework.. is this a simple html ?

Comment: this is a simple html, I am not using any framework...I am just learning html and CSS codes, and I was able to create a few pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way here is set **ul li** and **ul li a** line-height for 90px (as your ul height) and set padding-top and bottom to 0.

```
li { float: left; line-height: 90px; }
li a, .dropbtn {
     display: inline-block;
     color: black;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 0px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

But now your drop down list is broken. We fix it by setting line-height and height for **.dropdown-content** links like that:

```
.dropdown-content a {
     color: black;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
     line-height: normal;
     height: auto;
}
```

Now it looks fine, but your image is not aligned correctly. First of all, we need to set **display: inline-block** for our list elements.

```
li { float: left; line-height: 90px; display: inline-block; }
```

And then add **vertical-align: middle** for image

```
li img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

The last thing you want to know is unwanted hover on the first element. Remember that you can use nth-child, first-child, first-of-type combined with not selector to count elements. Add line:

```
li:first-child a:hover { background: none; }
```

And now everything should work just like you want it to. Anyway, few tips for future.

- Don't be afraid of using divs. It helps, helps a lot when you need to style and control elements on website. It's nothing more than just a container.
- Keep your CSS clean. It's **Cascading** Style Sheets. You've got in your CSS **li a** styles and after this **li a, .dropbtn** styles that override the previous one.

Don't give up and learn on. ;)

Comment: Thanks very much Kamil for your step by step, this is perfect! Yes I need to learn more. I was trying to use boostrap, but I think is better to improve my basic html and css codes first.

Comment: Yes, basic knowledge first if you want to understand what happen in frameworks like bootstrap. For everything will come the right time.

Comment: One thing that I notice is that when I use Firefox to check my html page, the logo is totally aligned, but when I use chrome or internet explore, the logo is not well aligned, this is expected?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, i forgot to check it on different browsers. Just remove **float: left;** in your li elements like that: `li { line-height: 90px; display: inline-block; }` You don't need floating when using display: inline-block;

Comment: Did not change anything..using internet explorer the quality of the logo is very bad and not aligned. Using chrome the logo is not aligned in the center. The best option is firefox...

Comment: I discovered the issue, I did no include in the first line of my html file "<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Interesting, it works fine for me without doctype after float fix.

Comment: Ok, i figured it out. It works fine with float fix and without doctype. And it works fine without float fix and with doctype. So you didn't remove float: left from your li element but don't worry about it, you should always use doctype so your solution is fine. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/thnhqr5v/#&togetherjs=s51V2VAft5) fiddle link for your answer.

I am using `margin` to align the navbar items in the center.

Comment: Just add **nav-item** class for `about` and `help` links and its done. Check the updated fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nayyarmannu/thnhqr5v/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=thnhqr5v) for the same.